# How to design tables so delete queries on related tables will only remove relations between them?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `teams` and `member` tables which is joined by `team_member` table. `teams` and `member` have many to many relationship. When I delete team I need to remove all relation pairs (team - member) from `team_member` and according record from `teams`. I cannot set in `team_member` table **ON DELETE CASCADE** because it will delete member (who can be related to many teams). Same strategy goes for deleting member. What is the best way to design it?

Current design:

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `organization` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_Organization_id` (`FK_Organization_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Organization_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Organization_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`id`)
  ON CASCADE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `team_member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK_Member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_Team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_Member_id` (`FK_Member_id`),
  KEY `FK_Team_id` (`FK_Team_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Team_id`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot set in team_member table ON DELETE CASCADE because it will
>   delete member

`ON DELETE CASCADE` doesn't work like that. The following two foreign key constraints will

- cascade deletes to team_member when a team is deleted, and
- cascade deletes to team_member when a member is deleted.

In no case will deleting a team also delete rows from members, and in no case will deleting a member also delete rows from teams.

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_Member_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Member_id`) 
  REFERENCES `member` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_Team_id`) 
  REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Build the tables, add some rows, and test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

```
delimiter $$
create trigger trig_remove_members_from_team
after delete on teams
for each row
begin
    delete from team_member where fk_team_id = OLD.id;
    -- You can perform additional insertions, updates or deletions
end $$
delimiter ;
```

This trigger will be executed just after you delete a row from `teams`.

Hope this helps